# My 2011 Macbook Pro won't start - folder with blinking '?'

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, hardware, partition

My Mac will not start up. I went to recovery mode and made a backup of everything on an external drive. Now the Mac only starts up from the external drive.

I have OS X 10.10, Yosemite. I tried to backup and restore but it failed.

Most of the time my internal hard disk is not mounted. I ran Disk Utility today and got the following message for my HD **Error: Partition Map check failed because no slices were found**

How can I fix my Mac and make it start without the external drive?

Comment: so the holding "cmd+r" during boot  is not working ?

Comment: it does work. Thats how I transferred all my data to my external hard disk.

Comment: Did you try formatting the internal disk?

Comment: Is that by erasing it? I tried that but it hangs halfway.

Comment: and when I go into recovery mode, it does not connect to my wifi. However it connects to it when I boot up from my external drive.

Comment: When I try to erase my interal drive. I get a error message of: Volume Erase Failed not enough space on drive

Comment: Partitioned my main internal hard drive that was names "Apple HDD 500.11 GB" However that is stuck on the phase "Waiting for disks to reappear"

Comment: That would say your disk can not be repaired.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a disk problem, dying.
In the Recovery Partition (start while holding CMD+R), start DiskUtility do Repair Disk.
Even when the issue is gone after that, prepare to have the disk replaced.